# r: Programatically Normalize & Name Variables

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have a dataset of two variables:

```
df<- data.frame(var1= rnorm(20, 15, 1.5), var2= rnorm(20, 7.5, 1))
```

I have a function that I can use to normalize them:

```
normFunc<- function(x){
  xAvg<- mean(x)
  return(x/xAvg)
}
```

Running the function manually works fine, see below on `var1`:

```
df$var1AVG<- normFunc(df$var1)
```

[image]

What I'd like to do is pass both variables into the function dynamically, using either a `for` loop, assign them to the dataframe and dynamically name them.

Comment: You can do `df %>% mutate_all(funs(AVG=normFunc))` if you don't mind the underscore in the name with `dplyr`

Comment: Are you familiar with `lapply`? Sounds like the perfect use case for it

Comment: Try `df[, paste0(names(df), "AVG")] <- lapply(df, normFunc)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `colMeans`/`colMeans2` to do this in a vectorized fashion

```
df / colMeans(df)
# or
df / matrixStats::colMeans2(as.matrix(df))
# yields
     var1      var2
1  0.9307705 0.4228236
2  1.9674104 0.9776180
3  1.1397295 0.4255726
4  2.0279614 0.9090271
5  0.9987836 0.4519303
...
```

with the data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(var1= rnorm(20, 15, 1.5), var2= rnorm(20, 7.5, 1))
```

**Addendum**

To address your question:

Alternatively, the method `Vectorize` is worth checking out in such a case or the `apply` family (with `vapply` being by far the most efficient one) - in your case `vapply(1:ncol(df), function (n) normFunc(df[,n]), numeric(nrow(df)))` would work. Or a well constructed loop can sometimes be even faster.

Comment: thanks this is helpful but my question is less about normalizing as it is about how to programmatically apply my function to generate the normalized variables.

Comment: @enriqueStateSpacias Fair enough, I'll edit my answer